# gSOAP C++ code on Windows vs Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gsoap, unauthorized

I'm using gSOAP with EWS via proxy services to connect to Exchange services. I've fully working C++ gSOAP code for sending message on Windows, but when I compile and run the same code on Ubuntu, I've got ***401 Unauthorized Error***, Why?

**On Windows:**

I've used the binaries of soapcpp2.exe and wsdl2h.exe to generate header files etc.

For compile and run: I'm using MobaXterm (a kind of Terminal)

Please anyone who are familiar with gSOAP help me to figure out the possible problem. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The **401 Unauthorized Error** requires HTTP authentication, either with HTTPS and basic authentication or with HTTP digest authentication. The proxy also likely requires authentication.

See the tutorial on [HTTP Digest Authentication](http://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html#How_to_connect_through_HTTP_proxies_and_use_HTTP_basic/digest_authentication,_NTLM_authentication_and_WS-Security_authentication)

Comment: But Alex I have to do this only with Basic Auth., I cann't use Digest Auth.

Comment: How do i know that when to authenticate for Proxy or when to endpoint server? plz help me i'm newbie in this area.

Comment: HTTP 401 "Unauthorized" is a Web server authentication challenge. This requires basic or digest authentication and recommend using HTTPS (basic auth sends credentials in the clear). I don't know why there is a difference on Ubunto as you describe, perhaps the proxy authenticates to the server??

Comment: Here i'm sharing the link of same question with the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403847/401-unauthorized-in-ubuntu-but-works-fine-in-windows-moba-xterm-gsoap-ews Hope this help you to understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I also would like to know that does it matter to generate gsoap engine files with the windows binaries like wsdl2h.exe and soapcpp2.exe, and use those files in Ubuntu to run the program. Does it could be the reason of this problem?